# Generate rollno for classes & sections

Tags: sql-server

### Table: In SqlServer2008

create table studentreg(id int indentity, rollno int identity, name varchar(5), name varchar(50), class varchar(3) identity, sec varchar(3) identity)

### Problem:

```
id   rollno     name    class   sec
```

---

```
1   101     John        I       A
2   101     Smith       I       B
3   101     Michael     II      A
4   102     Johnson     I       A
```

Question:

I want to auto generate rollno without entering it (i mean internally). I know it possible by identity. But i want to generate rollno for Class I, Sec A (starting from 101 & increment with 1) and again Class I, Sec B (again start for 101 and increment with 1). Like that for other classes & Sec. You can better understand with above diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY class, sec ORDER BY NAME) + 100 roll_no,
       id,
       NAME,
       class,
       sec
FROM   tablename
```